# Can I add event listener on the site that is not mine?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know about all changes in some DOM element on one site that is not mine so I could receive browser notifications about DOM element changes.
How could I do this if I can't write a code on the site?
I want to use this approach:

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('some-id');
 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
 
// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

```html
<div id="some-id"></div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: How is your code going to be run on this other website?

Comment: This was my question.

Comment: yet you haven't given us anything to work with. Do you want to have this in a browser plugin of some sort? Do you want it run on every single user's machine? Do you want it only on yours? Your question is pretty much equivalent to "how do I do stuff" - yes, it _can_ be answered but it will require some clarification.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: I need it for myself. I just want to see changes on the site before others see them so I could react on them faster. Maybe later I will want to make plugin for others.

Comment: You can create an `interval` that does an ajax request for example every 2 seconds and compares response with previous response , and if they differ then the target page's DOM is updated.

Comment: also check here for real-time update help http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/06/how-to-build-a-realtime-jquery-plugin/

Comment: you don't need to publish your browser extension. Extensions are doing just that what you want: adding HTML and/or JavaScript to specific or all pages. You are writing simple *.js files to do this. You can also add and call your own functions via browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add client side code to any website. That is the main behaviour of browser extensions for example.

But you can also just take your code and paste it to your browser's console (Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>)

In this example we will obeserve the `<div id="question-header">` of this SO page.

```
// select the target node
var target = document.getElementById('question-header');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
    if (permission === "granted") {
      var notification = new Notification("Something has changed!");
    }
  });
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) { 
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Then execute this to test if it is working:

```
var node = document.createElement("b");                
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Hello new item");
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("question-header").appendChild(node);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with something like this :

```
$(function(){
    var keep = '';
    var ajaxurl = "http://foo.bar";

    setInterval(function(){
        $.get( ajaxurl, { sample_data : 'test' }, function(response){

            var log = "<p>Checked</p>";

            if( keep != '' && keep !== response )
                log = "<p>Something has changed</p>";

                $('.log-container').append( log );

        });

    }, 2000);
});
```

but you can do a more advanced thing with pusherJS https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js

Comment: If I right understand it will send a query every 2 secs and check if something was changed. That is good but would be better if I could get notification on DOM change without quering. Thank you anyway because this is useful for me info.